# MySQL structure for storing numeric values that differ drastically

Tags: mysql, decimal

I have a column with numeric values that differ drastically:

```
123.072
2
0.00012
851
1234
0.1
12
0.531211
etc.
```

I've tried using float and decimal but when I enter `0.023` for example, it just rounds the value as `0`. I can't afford to round these numbers.

What structure type and length should I be using?

Comment: What is the exact number(ideally) of decimal points you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the range(length) of your decimal:

```
decimal(number,number)
```

Comment: `0.023` needs at least `DECIMAL(3,3)`.  The first number is the total number of digits and the second is the digits after the decimal point.